# Picking a logo in Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Does anyone know how to put a logo on the "picker" for Google maps?

I found a nice hello world, but it is v2 :'{ (is it worth trying this?)

Demo maps hello world APIv2:
https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/map-infowindow?hl=pt-BR

Any suggestions to solve this challenge?

Comment: A jpg or png...
Important is I choose de geolocation of this customized pick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html

I would make a custom info box. You can just:

- include the image within the html and
- use no background
- make it visible by default
- include no way to close the infobox